# Device Descriptor read/8 error-61

Tags: usb, raspberrypi

I'm at a loss, I have tried everything but I can't get the usb ports to work.
This is the output of "dmesg". When I plug my External HDD it's not detected, I'm running: Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-1008-raspi2  on a raspberry pi

```
[    0.919738] pci 0000:01:00.0: [1106:3483] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    0.919809] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
[    0.920002] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3cold
[    0.920272] pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to get arch_dma_ops
[    0.922824] pci_bus 0000:01: busn_res: [bus 01] end is updated to 01
[    0.922866] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 14: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    0.922893] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x600000fff 64                                                                                                             bit]
[    0.922934] pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    0.922958] pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    0.923219] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    0.923407] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 42
[    0.923754] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 42
[    0.923986] pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    0.982941] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.985138] iproc-rng200 fe104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    0.985554] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3ec00000 mem_size:0x40000                                                                                                             000(1024 MiB)
[    0.986307] gpiomem-bcm2835 fe200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0xfe2                                                                                                             00000
[    0.986647] cacheinfo: Unable to detect cache hierarchy for CPU 0
[    1.312136] loop: module loaded
[    1.314343] spi-bcm2835 fe204000.spi: could not get clk: -517
[    1.315053] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.315096] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    1.315268] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    1.315490] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    1.315546] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.315585] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.315615] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.315683] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.315708] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.315757] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.316070] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.316141] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus numbe                                                                                                             r 1
[    1.316680] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: hcc params 0x002841eb hci version 0x100 qu                                                                                                             irks 0x0000001000000890
[    1.316865] genirq: irq_chip Brcm_MSI did not update eff. affinity mask of ir                                                                                                             q 43
[    1.317408] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bc                                                                                                             dDevice= 5.03
[    1.317435] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=                                                                                                             1
[    1.317458] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.317476] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.3.0-1008-raspi2 xhci-hcd
[    1.317495] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.318034] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.318096] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.318553] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.318582] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus numbe                                                                                                             r 2
[    1.318614] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    1.318912] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bc                                                                                                             dDevice= 5.03
[    1.318937] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=                                                                                                             1
[    1.318958] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.318975] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.3.0-1008-raspi2 xhci-hcd
[    1.318994] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.319493] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.319554] hub 2-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.320381] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    1.320673] dwc_otg fe980000.usb: base=(____ptrval____)
[    1.522916] Core Release: 2.80a
[    1.522935] Setting default values for core params
[    1.522968] Finished setting default values for core params
[    1.652170] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.725425] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    1.725443] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    1.725459] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    1.725476] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    1.725531] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    1.726556] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1043: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = ffff0                                                                                                             00010de1000 dma = 0x00000000eb500000 len=9024
[    1.726601] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
               Non-periodic Split Transactions
               Periodic Split Transactions
               High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
               Interrupt/Control Split Transaction hack enabled
[    1.726638] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    1.726677] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:496: MPHI regs_base at ffff0000102c5200
[    1.726776] dwc_otg fe980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.726812] dwc_otg fe980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number                                                                                                              3
[    1.726859] dwc_otg fe980000.usb: irq 24, io mem 0x00000000
[    1.726917] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    1.726932] Init: Power Port (0)
[    1.727199] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bc                                                                                                             dDevice= 5.03
[    1.727227] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=                                                                                                             1
[    1.727249] usb usb3: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.727268] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.3.0-1008-raspi2 dwc_otg_hcd
[    1.727287] usb usb3: SerialNumber: fe980000.usb
[    1.727850] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.727910] hub 3-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.728593] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    1.728601] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    1.728608] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    1.728618] Module dwc_common_port init
[    1.729092] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.729519] i2c /dev entries driver
[    1.732076] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    1.732314] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    1.732623] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.40.0-ioctl (2019-01-18) initialised: dm-d                                                                                                             evel@redhat.com
[    1.732758] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=600000 max=1500000
[    1.734033] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.734040] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.734214] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    1.734362] Error: Driver 'sdhost-bcm2835' is already registered, aborting...
[    1.734369] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.736046] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.736129] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.736573] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = (____ptrval____)
[    1.738686] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.760971] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    1.761042] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.761180] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.761635] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.761666] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    1.766654] Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: 8a543b008                                                                                                             3d12dc0ff5d2ba72b66d5347614cc85'
[    1.766756] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
[    1.780463] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    1.785333] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    1.886988] Key type big_key registered
[    1.912018] Key type encrypted registered
[    1.912044] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    1.912067] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    1.912088] ima: Allocated hash algorithm: sha1
[    1.912141] No architecture policies found
[    1.912175] evm: Initialising EVM extended attributes:
[    1.912182] evm: security.selinux
[    1.912188] evm: security.SMACK64
[    1.912194] evm: security.SMACK64EXEC
[    1.912199] evm: security.SMACK64TRANSMUTE
[    1.912205] evm: security.SMACK64MMAP
[    1.912210] evm: security.apparmor
[    1.912216] evm: security.ima
[    1.912221] evm: security.capability
[    1.912227] evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1
[    1.915222] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    1.915277] fe201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0xfe201000 (irq = 18, base_baud                                                                                                              = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    1.916613] printk: console [ttyS0] disabled
[    1.916647] fe215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x0 (irq = 21, base_baud = 6250000                                                                                                             0) is a 16550
[    2.037445] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    2.283008] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.311001] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -61
[    2.417135] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.460732] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -61
[    2.743351] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.903601] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    3.162866] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    3.273126] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[    3.480547] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    3.487747] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    3.492341] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains drive                                                                                                             r
[    3.499898] spi-bcm2835 fe204000.spi: no tx-dma configuration found - not usi                                                                                                             ng dma mode
[    3.508423] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -61
[    3.514766] brcmstb_thermal fd5d2200.thermal: registered AVS TMON of-sensor d                                                                                                             river
[    3.522777] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    3.528882] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: mmc-bcm2835: Unable to initialise DMA                                                                                                              channel. Falling back to PIO
[    3.564772] hctosys: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
[    3.570155] of_cfs_init
[    3.572697] of_cfs_init: OK
[    3.580649] Freeing unused kernel memory: 4096K
[    3.584445] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    3.592376] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    3.598610] Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found
[    3.599503] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    3.604363] Run /init as init process
[    3.612637] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    3.620146] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    3.627952] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    3.648401] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -61
[    3.674291] random: fast init done
[    3.695840] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    3.701769] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.709197] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.717432] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.789048] usb usb2-port2: attempt power cycle
[    4.091681] usb_phy_generic phy: phy supply vcc not found, using dummy regula                                                                                                             tor
[    4.099919] bcmgenet fd580000.genet: failed to get enet clock
[    4.105790] bcmgenet fd580000.genet: GENET 5.0 EPHY: 0x0000
[    4.115514] bcmgenet fd580000.genet: failed to get enet-wol clock
[    4.121864] bcmgenet fd580000.genet: failed to get enet-eee clock
[    4.128167] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    4.146146] mmc0: Failed to set 32-bit DMA mask.
[    4.150906] mmc0: No suitable DMA available - falling back to PIO
[    4.196252] mmc0: SDHCI controller on fe340000.emmc2 [fe340000.emmc2] using P                                                                                                             IO
[    4.261488] [drm] No displays found. Consider forcing hotplug if HDMI is atta                                                                                                             ched
[    4.268409] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    4.269174] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound fe600000.firmwarekms (ops vc4_fkms_ops [vc                                                                                                             4])
[    4.291686] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    4.298437] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[    4.304465] [drm] Setting vblank_disable_immediate to false because get_vblan                                                                                                             k_timestamp == NULL
[    4.309836] mmc0: new ultra high speed DDR50 SDHC card at address aaaa
[    4.318699] [drm] Initialized vc4 0.0.0 20140616 for soc:gpu on minor 0
[    4.329188] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SL32G 29.7 GiB
[    4.340259]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    4.508398] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    4.748406] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    4.772544] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -61
[    4.884170] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    4.908414] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -61
[    4.929681] unimac-mdio unimac-mdio.-19: DMA mask not set
[    4.948125] libphy: bcmgenet MII bus: probed
[    4.987366] unimac-mdio unimac-mdio.-19: Broadcom UniMAC MDIO bus
[    5.176128] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    5.308347] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    5.548339] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    5.660248] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[    5.856350] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    5.880410] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -61
[    5.992114] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    6.016364] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -61
[    6.156198] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

This is the main Errors:

```
[    4.508398] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    4.748406] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    4.772544] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -61
[    4.884170] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    4.908414] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -61
[    4.929681] unimac-mdio unimac-mdio.-19: DMA mask not set
[    4.948125] libphy: bcmgenet MII bus: probed
[    4.987366] unimac-mdio unimac-mdio.-19: Broadcom UniMAC MDIO bus
[    5.176128] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    5.308347] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    5.548339] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    5.660248] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[    5.856350] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    5.880410] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -61
[    5.992114] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    6.016364] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -61
[    6.156198] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Comment: What OS/release are you running?  You gave a linux kernel, but not your OS & release.

Comment: I see the same error for all USB ports coming from my docking station. Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [error number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532546/209677) ([also here](https://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html)):

```
$ errno 61
ENODATA 61 No data available

$ grep '61' /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h
#define ENODATA         61      /* No data available */
```

[Which means](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/ioctl.html): "No message on the STREAM head read queue.".

So probably if you have the right permissions you don't receive any data from the device due to a hardware failure or an [invalid driver](https://lwn.net/Articles/13175/).